# Find nearest line from linestring PostGIS

Tags: postgis, psql

I want to find the closet line to a given point using PostGIS on postgres db. But I can't extract lines from LineString data structure using PostGIS's functions.

This is one of my LineString example:

> LINESTRING(51.4108421 35.7576013,51.4103935 35.7577687,51.41033 35.7578188)

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This should be simple. What have your tried?

Comment: Please only ask one question per question. Your title doesn't match your immediate issue.